# vanilla js 'keyup' works but not 'submit' event listener on form element

Tags: javascript, dom, dom-events

Please find my code below for a simple vanilla javascript weather api call to fetch data and display on the same page. For now, please ignore the debounce and handleInoutText functions, I am hard coding a city name to fetch data.

```js
'use strict';

(function() {
 const inputEl    = document.querySelector(".search-placholder");
 // Get the form element.
 const formEl     = document.querySelector('form.weatherdata-form');
 const currTemp   = document.querySelector('.current-temperature');
 const weather    = document.querySelector('.weather-description');
 const searchBar  = document.querySelector('.search-bar');
 const resultArea = document.querySelector('.result-area');
 let cityName = '';

 const debounce = (func, wait, immediate) => {
  var timeout;
  return function() {
   var context = this, args = arguments;
   var later = function() {
    timeout = null;
    if (!immediate) func.apply(context, args);
   };
   var callNow = immediate && !timeout;
   clearTimeout(timeout);
   timeout = setTimeout(later, wait);
   if (callNow) func.apply(context, args);
  };
 };

 const handleSearchText = debounce((e) => {
   cityName = e.target.value,
   inputEl.placeholder = cityName
 }, 250);

 inputEl.addEventListener("keyup", handleSearchText);
 // make request to openweatherapi & make api call
 const getWeatherdata = function(event) {
  const url = `http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=London&appid=2489ed561dc99d173a2f394574bc107e`;
  const response = fetch(url)
   .then(result => result.json())
   .then(data => {
    console.log(data)
    searchBar.style.display = "none";
    resultArea.style.display = "block";
    let k = parseInt(data.main.temp);
    let final = Math.floor(9/5 * (k -273) + 32);
    currTemp.textContent = final;
    weather.textContent = data.weather[0].description;
   });

 }

 formEl.addEventListener('keyup', getWeatherdata);

 // formEl.addEventListener("submit", getWeatherdata);

})();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>My cool weather app</title>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
</head>
<body>
  <main>
    <div class="search-container">
      <div class="search-bar">
        <form class="weatherdata-form">
          <i class="fa fa-search fa-3x" id="icon"></i>
          <input type="text" class="search-placholder" 
                placeholder="Type city to find weather..." 
                name="city-name" />
          <button type="submit">Submit</button>
        </form>
      </div>
      <div class="result-area">
        <span>Weather Today:
          <p class="current-temperature"></p>
        </span>
        <p class="weather-description"></p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </main>
  <script src="index.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

I am using an example city name currently to fetch data but the submit event listener is not working. Do I need to change my html?

Comment: Why even use a form and a submit event? Do you plan on actually submitting the form on the edge case the user doesn't have javascript enabled? Remove the form and put a click event on the button.

Comment: You dont prevent the default action of the form submit, which is to submit the form and in turn is going to navigate away from the current page to the action url of the form. In your case since you dont specify one you basically just reload the page

Comment: @PatrickEvans hmm I had preventedDefault earlier - deleted in trial and error I think - now I have removed the form coz a normal submit button click should do - that did not help really.

Answer (score 0):

This was my bad - I had a click event on a button I was not clicking! I wanted my code to run on enter - so I added event listener on input element keyup - if keycode was 13, the function executes like in snippet:

```js
'use strict';

(function() {
 const inputEl = document.querySelector(".search-placeholder");
 // Get the form element.
 const btnEl = document.querySelector('.btn-submit');
 const currTemp = document.querySelector('.current-temperature');
 const weather = document.querySelector('.weather-description');
 const searchBar = document.querySelector('.search-bar');
 const resultArea = document.querySelector('.result-area');
 let cityName = '';

 const debounce = (func, wait, immediate) => {
  var timeout;
  return function() {
   var context = this, args = arguments;
   var later = function() {
    timeout = null;
    if (!immediate) func.apply(context, args);
   };
   var callNow = immediate && !timeout;
   clearTimeout(timeout);
   timeout = setTimeout(later, wait);
   if (callNow) func.apply(context, args);
  };
 };

 const handleSearchText = debounce((e) => {
  cityName = e.target.value,
  inputEl.placeholder = cityName
 }, 250);

 inputEl.addEventListener("keyup", handleSearchText);
 // make request to openweatherapi & make api call
 const getWeatherdata = function(event) {
  const url = `http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=London&appid=2489ed561dc99d173a2f394574bc107e`;
  const response = fetch(url)
   .then(result => result.json())
   .then(data => {
    console.log(data)
    searchBar.style.display = "none";
    resultArea.style.display = "block";
    let k = parseInt(data.main.temp);
    let final = Math.floor(9/5 * (k -273) + 32);
    currTemp.textContent = final;
    weather.textContent = data.weather[0].description;
    const img = new Image();
    img.setAttribute('src', `http://openweathermap.org/img/wn/${data.weather[0].icon}@2x.png`);
    img.setAttribute('class', 'mark');
    resultArea.appendChild(img);
   });
 }

 inputEl.addEventListener('keyup', function(e) {
  if(e.keyCode === 13) {
   getWeatherdata()
  }
 });

})();
```

```css
.btn-submit {
 display: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
 <title>My cool weather app</title>
 <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
</head>
<body>
 <main>
  <div class="search-container">
   <div class="search-bar">
    <i class="fa fa-search fa-3x" id="icon"></i>
    <input type="text" class="search-placeholder" placeholder="Type city to find weather..." name="city-name"/>
    <button class="btn-submit" type="submit">Submit</button>
   </div>
   <div class="result-area">
    <span>Weather Today:<p class="current-temperature"></p></span>
    <p class="weather-description"></p>
   </div>
  </div>
 </main>
 <script src="index.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Hope this helps someone!